# How can I know what functions to call when programming Android features?

Tags: android, android-widget

Basically, I don't know what functions & XML attributes to provide when programming a specific Android feature; eg, Android Search Widget with Edittext in the middle, magnifier glass on the right, and a custom icon on the left.

From where I can find out what methods, parameters & XML attributes to call when doing a specific Android task?

Fron what sources can we find out how to program specific Android feature?   Are there some overall programming pictures to reference?

Praiser

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know about Android development can be found at [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/index.html).